# How to use three conditions with AND operator in while loop in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How to use three conditions with AND operator in while loop in PHP
Here is my code:

```
$query = "select * from agent_profile where status = 1";
$run = mysqli_query($con, $query);

$pricequery = "select * from airport_parking where airport_name = '$airport' AND '$parking_start_time' >= start_time ";
$resultprice = mysqli_query($con, $pricequery);

$squery = "select * from agent_services where agent_id = '$crnt_id' AND service_type = '$service_type' ";
$srun = mysqli_query($con, $squery);


if ($run && $resultprice && $squery) {
    while (($datarow = mysqli_fetch_array($run)) AND ($getdata = mysqli_fetch_array($resultprice)) AND ($sdata = mysqli_fetch_array($srun))) {
    }
```

Comment: AND will keep the while until all the conditions are true, that means, it will run until all your fetch records of all selects only if you have the same amount of record on all  them. You probably need to use OR condition in this case.

Comment: A recomendation is to use array_map or 1 while for each variable.

Comment: You either need to combine those 3 SQL queries into one or fetch all the queries separately and merge them in PHP which would be a waste of resource. Look at UNION or how to JOIN queries for SQL

Comment: I suggest U do a while loop for each query seperately

Comment: But i want to filter that's why i want to use one while loop  and filter the data

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$query = "select * from agent_profile where status=1
        UNION
        select * from airport_parking where airport_name = '$airport' AND  '$parking_start_time' >= start_time 
        UNION
        select * from agent_services where agent_id = '$crnt_id' AND service_type='$service_type';";
$run = mysqli_query($con,$query);

if(strlen($run) <> ''){

    while (($datarow = mysqli_fetch_array($run)))
   {
       $column_name = $datarow['column_name'];
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it returns nothing. I mean that It shows there is no data but I have data in databaase related to search

Comment: @Rayn: Please check now.

Comment: Can you tell me please now, how to save values in variables in while condition from database?

Comment: @Rayn: Please check now.

Comment: Still, it returns the else statement even if  statement is true

Comment: @Rayn: In sql query take same number of column in three query;

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. What do you want to say?

Comment: @Rayn: SELECT column_name(1) , column_name(2) FROM table1 UNION SELECT column_name(1), column_name(2) FROM table2;

Comment: @Rayn: Query gives null value.

Comment: @Rayn: Which value fetch on page? Can you told me?

Comment: I want to fetch different values from these three tables

Comment: I can't upload pic here because here is no option to upload pic

Comment: Edit your answer and click on image icon then drop or select image.